# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when adding UITabBarController into UIView

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, subview

I programmatically add UITabBarController into UIView. That causes console warnings I can't understand and remove. Despite that, in simulator everything is placed as desired.

```
    final class MainController: UIViewController {
    
    let searchArea = SearchArea()
    let tabBarContainer = UIView()
    let tabBarControl = TabBarController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        view.addSubview(searchArea)
        searchArea.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        searchArea.addConstraints(
            .alignTopWithTop(of: safeArea),
            .alignLeadingWithLeading(of: safeArea),
            .alignTrailingWithTrailing(of: safeArea),
            .alignHeight(with: safeArea, mult: 0.05)
        )
        searchArea.setupView()
        
        view.addSubview(tabBarContainer)
        tabBarContainer.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tabBarContainer.addConstraints(
            .alignTopWithBottom(of: searchArea),
            .alignLeadingWithLeading(of: safeArea),
            .alignTrailingWithTrailing(of: safeArea),
            .alignBottomWithBottom(of: safeArea)
        )
        
        tabBarControl.view.frame = tabBarContainer.bounds
        tabBarControl.tabBar.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tabBarContainer.addSubview(tabBarControl.view)
        addChild(tabBarControl)
        tabBarControl.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
}
```

This causes console output:

> 2023-06-12 17:55:46.716982+0300 BFB[66775:3057149] [LayoutConstraints]
> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
> of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try
> this:         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
> don't expect;         (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint
> or constraints and fix it.    (Note: If you're seeing
> NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
> to the documentation for the UIView property
> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003fe7340 h=-&- v=--& UINavigationBar:0x12f21ecd0.minY == 0   (active, names:
> '|':UILayoutContainerView:0x12f21eb30 )>",
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003ff1e00 h=-&- v=--& UINavigationBar:0x12f21ecd0.height == 44   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fef110 V:[UINavigationBar:0x12f21ecd0]-(0)-[UIFocusContainerGuide:0x6000023f4870'UINavigationControllerContentFocusContainerGuide']
> (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003feee40 UIFocusContainerGuide:0x6000023f4870'UINavigationControllerContentFocusContainerGuide'.bottom
> == UILayoutContainerView:0x12f21eb30.bottom   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003f902d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'
> UILayoutContainerView:0x12f21eb30.height == 0   (active)>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fef110
> V:[UINavigationBar:0x12f21ecd0]-(0)-[UIFocusContainerGuide:0x6000023f4870'UINavigationControllerContentFocusContainerGuide']
> (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Unfortunately, I do not understand what causes this conflict. Because I do nothing with UINavigationBar - it's created by UITabBarController. This message appears when I add this line of code:

```
tabBarContainer.addSubview(tabBarControl.view)
```

Of course, I set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false (it's not shown in sample code but I did).

Also, I set priority of my constraints to .defaultLow (in order to resolve conflicts with come constraints that are created automatically) but it didn't help.

Comment: It's about a UINavigationBar. I believe it's an iOS bug unrelated to your code.

Comment: I added. symbolic breakpoint as Xcode recommended... it brings me into assembler code. I used this article to decode it - https://karthikkeyan.medium.com/debugging-uiviewalertforunsatisfiableconstraints-47697696c7c but unfortunately, I can't find  adress of constraints and view as described in article.

Comment: Also, when I try to debug view hierarchy, Xcode tells me a lot "[API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0xa5cb420d) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]" errors in console..